# phonegap build ios splashscreen

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, splash-screen, phonegap-build

I have built an app using Phonegap build and am trying to get the splash screens working correctly on each device. Here is how I have included them in my config.xml:

```
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png" width="960" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape.png" width="480" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="320" />
```

And all of the images exist in the correct folder.

The problem I am having is that on my iPad, in landscape mode the correct splash screen appears - but in portrait the same splash screen seems to appear(streached and cropped to fit)

How do I get the correct splash screen to display?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with this,

I set height properties on each of the lines and realised that one of the image's was the incorrect size:

```
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" height="784" />
```

when I should have had:

```
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
```

Stupid on my part, but hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for `IOS` -

```
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
```